# Authenticating to Open Wifi with Linux CLI dies with (reason=3)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ethernet

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and tried the following...  I have a Netgear WNA-1100 USB stick plugged in and used `/etc/init.d/network-manager stop` to disable NetworkManager, since it interferes with [`iwconfig`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/iwconfig8.html).

```
sudo ip link set down dev wlan1
sudo iwconfig wlan1 mode Managed
sudo iwconfig wlan1 key open
sudo iwconfig wlan1 channel auto
sudo iwconfig wlan1 essid PacificInn
sudo ip link set up dev wlan1
sudo iwconfig wlan1
sudo dhclient wlan1
```

Initially, the card associates to the AP (output from `dmesg`):

```
[ 2261.592909] wlan1: authenticate with 00:0f:61:8d:06:80 (try 1)
[ 2261.594710] wlan1: associate with 00:0f:61:8d:06:80 (try 1)
[ 2261.598406] wlan1: RX AssocResp from 00:0f:61:8d:06:80 (capab=0xc21 status=0 
    aid=1)
```

Then it quickly disassociates:

```
[ 2261.604312] wlan1: disassociating from 00:0f:61:8d:06:80 by local choice 
   (reason=3)
```

Reason 3 is has to do with authentication, but this AP is *Open*, and my config specified *open* authentication.  Why is my wifi card disassociating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much frustration, I discovered that `wpa_supplicant` was running in the background, and was killing the connection just as soon as I authenticated.  After I killed `wpa_supplicant`, I had no problems joining the wifi AP.